# Eclipse Debugger missing source file c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, mingw

I'm running into the following error when I attempt to walk through the debugger.

> Can't find a source file at "../../../../src/gcc-4.7.1/libgcc/unwind-sjlj.c" 
>   Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.

I am using the MINGW64 compiler.

I have tried locating the file, I have tried most of the proposed solutions on other similar questions, but I haven't been able to find something too close to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to reinstall MINIGW for anyone who has this happen to them.